# Cannot see apps page - always get redirected

Tags: authentication, facebook-like

I am trying to load up http://developers.facebook.com/apps page but i always get redirected to  my 'adverts & pages' page.  I cant add the Developer app either as i get redirected also to the same page.  Im simply trying to register my website as an app.  I need to set a fb:app_id value for our Like buttons

I have a recorded mobile number & credit card so our page should be verified

Any thoughts ?.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently logged in as a page account and not a real user account.  Only user accounts can create facebook apps.